# Snake game in C++ (using SFML)

Tags: c++, game, c++11, sfml

I haven't done any programming in a while, and I'm getting back into it. I made this Snake clone to refresh me a bit, and I would like to get some feedback in the "elegance" and "well-done"-ness of the code.

### main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    Game::run();
    return 0;
}
```

### Game.h

```
#ifndef __GAME_H__
#define __GAME_H__

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <random>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

enum class Direction {UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT};
enum class MoveEvent {EAT, COLLIDE};

class Game
{
public:

    static void run();

private:

    static sf::RenderWindow *                   window;
    static int                                  score;
    static int                                  level;
    static bool                                 alive;

    static std::pair<int, int>                  foodLocation;

    // Random Number Generation for X
    static const int                            rangex_from;
    static const int                            rangex_to;
    static std::random_device                   rand_devX;
    static std::mt19937                         generatorX;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int>   distrX;

    static const int                            rangey_from;
    static const int                            rangey_to;
    static std::random_device                   rand_devY;
    static std::mt19937                         generatorY;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int>   distrY;

    static std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>     snake_body;
    static Direction                            snake_direction;
    static Direction                            new_direction;

    static std::pair<int, int>                  getNewFoodLocation();
    static void                                 moveSnake();
    static void                                 draw();
    static bool                                 collides(std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>);

    static sf::Texture tile;
    static sf::Texture body;
    static sf::Texture food;

    static sf::Sprite tile_spr;
    static sf::Sprite body_spr;
    static sf::Sprite food_spr;
};

#endif
```

### Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

#include <iostream>

// Initialization of static variables

sf::RenderWindow * Game::window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Snake", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
int Game::score = 0;
int Game::level = 1;
bool Game::alive = true;

const int Game::rangex_from =    0;
const int Game::rangex_to =     39;
const int Game::rangey_from =    0;
const int Game::rangey_to =     29;

std::random_device      Game::rand_devX;
std::random_device      Game::rand_devY;

std::mt19937            Game::generatorX(Game::rand_devX());
std::mt19937            Game::generatorY(Game::rand_devY());

std::uniform_int_distribution<int>   Game::distrX(Game::rangex_from, Game::rangex_to);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int>   Game::distrY(Game::rangey_from, Game::rangey_to);

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>                    Game::snake_body;
Direction                                           Game::snake_direction;
Direction                                           Game::new_direction;
std::pair<int, int>                                 Game::foodLocation = Game::getNewFoodLocation();

sf::Texture                                         Game::body;
sf::Texture                                         Game::tile;
sf::Texture                                         Game::food;
sf::Sprite                                          Game::body_spr;
sf::Sprite                                          Game::tile_spr;
sf::Sprite                                          Game::food_spr;


std::pair<int, int> Game::getNewFoodLocation()
{
    std::pair<int, int> temporalLocation;

    do
    {
        temporalLocation = std::pair<int, int>(Game::distrX(Game::generatorX), Game::distrY(Game::generatorY));
    } while (collides(temporalLocation, Game::snake_body));

    return temporalLocation;
}

bool Game::collides(std::pair<int, int> coordinate, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> body)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < body.size(); i++)
        if (coordinate.first == body[i].first && coordinate.second == body[i].second)
            return true;

    return false;
}

void Game::moveSnake()
{
    std::pair<int, int> new_head_pos;

    // Calculates the new position the snakes head will take
    switch (new_direction)
    {
    case Direction::UP:
        if (snake_body[0].second - 1 >= rangey_from)
            new_head_pos.second = snake_body[0].second - 1;
        else
            new_head_pos.second = rangey_to;
        new_head_pos.first = snake_body[0].first;       
        break;

    case Direction::DOWN:
        if (snake_body[0].second + 1 <= rangey_to)
            new_head_pos.second = snake_body[0].second + 1;
        else
            new_head_pos.second = rangey_from;
        new_head_pos.first = snake_body[0].first;       
        break;

    case Direction::LEFT:
        if (snake_body[0].first - 1 >= rangex_from)
            new_head_pos.first = snake_body[0].first - 1;
        else
            new_head_pos.first = rangex_to;
        new_head_pos.second = snake_body[0].second;
        break;

    case Direction::RIGHT:
        if (snake_body[0].first + 1 <= rangex_to)
            new_head_pos.first = snake_body[0].first + 1;
        else
            new_head_pos.first = rangex_from;
        new_head_pos.second = snake_body[0].second;
        break;
    }

    //Fast hack <_<
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> body_minus_tail = snake_body;
    body_minus_tail.pop_back();

    // Checks if the snake will collide with its own body
    if(collides(new_head_pos, body_minus_tail))
    { 
        std::cout << "You Lost!     Score: " << score << std::endl;
        alive = false;
    }

    if(new_head_pos == foodLocation)
    { 
        score++;
        snake_body.insert(snake_body.begin(), new_head_pos);
        foodLocation = getNewFoodLocation();
    }
    else
    {
        snake_body.insert(snake_body.begin(), new_head_pos);
        snake_body.pop_back();
    }
    snake_direction = new_direction;
}

void Game::run()
{
    window->setFramerateLimit(60);

    snake_body.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(2, 0));
    snake_body.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(1, 0));
    snake_body.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(0, 0));

    snake_direction = Direction::RIGHT;
    new_direction   = Direction::RIGHT;

    body.loadFromFile("body.png");
    tile.loadFromFile("tile.png");
    food.loadFromFile("food.png");

    body_spr.setTexture(body);
    tile_spr.setTexture(tile);
    food_spr.setTexture(food);

    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time time1;

    while (window->isOpen())

    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window->pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                // Calculates the new direction the snake is heading based on user input
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                switch (event.key.code)
                {
                case sf::Keyboard::Up:
                case sf::Keyboard::W:
                    if (snake_direction != Direction::DOWN)
                        new_direction = Direction::UP;
                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::Right:
                case sf::Keyboard::D:
                    if (snake_direction != Direction::LEFT)
                        new_direction = Direction::RIGHT;
                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::Down:
                case sf::Keyboard::S:
                    if (snake_direction != Direction::UP)
                        new_direction = Direction::DOWN;
                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::Left:
                case sf::Keyboard::A:
                    if (snake_direction != Direction::RIGHT)
                        new_direction = Direction::LEFT;
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window->close();
                break;
            }

        }

        time1 = clock.getElapsedTime();
        if (time1.asMilliseconds() >= 1000/20)
        {
            moveSnake();
            clock.restart();
        }

        if (!alive)
            window->close();

        window->clear();
        draw();
        window->display();

    }
}

void::Game::draw()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rangex_to; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < rangey_to; j++)
        {
            tile_spr.setPosition(i*16, j*16);
            window->draw(tile_spr);
        }

    food_spr.setPosition(foodLocation.first*16, foodLocation.second*16);
    window->draw(food_spr);

    for (int i = 0; i < snake_body.size(); i++)
    {
        body_spr.setPosition(snake_body[i].first*16, snake_body[i].second*16);
        window->draw(body_spr);
    }
}
```

Comment: A tiny detail: don't declare names with `__`, (`__GAME_H__`), that's a reserved prefix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654

Answer (score 5):

#### Basic structure

With all its members `static`, your `Game` class looks a whole lot like a namespace. I'd either make it a namespace, or else make everything that's specific to a particular game (e.g., the current score) non-static so that each game object really represents an actual game. The latter is *probably* preferable, but either is an improvement on the current situation.

Worse, your `Game` class looks a lot like what's often called a "God class". A single class that tries to be all, know all, and do all. By lumping everything together into a single class, you've lost most of the benefits of using classes in the first place, and just written basic block-structured code about like you would in something like C, but with `Game::` tacked onto the beginnings of many (most?) of the names.

I'd rather see (for example) one class for the snake, another for a food object, and (possibly) another for the game board (or possibly just for a tile).

#### Random number generation

I don't see any use in having separate random number generators for your X and Y coordinates. Quite the contrary, you're almost certainly better off using a single generator for both. Likewise, there's no point in creating separate instances of `random_device` to initialize each.

#### Wrapping numbers

A fair amount of the logic in your game code is devoted to the fairly simple job of ensuring that a number always stays within a particular range (and if you try to decrement below the beginning or increment above the end, wrapping around to the other end).

At least in my opinion, that sounds a lot like the specification of a small class:

```
class bounded { 
    int current;
    int lower;
    int upper;
public:
    bounded(int lower, int upper) : upper(upper), lower(lower) {}

    bounded &operator++() { 
       ++current;
       if (current >= upper)
           current = lower;
       return *this;
    }

    bounded &operator--() { 
        --current;
        if (current < lower)
            current = upper;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

For other purposes, you could add things like assignment, `+=`, `-=`, and so on, but for this game I believe increment and decrement are all you really need.

Using this, the code for the main loop of the game is simplified considerably:

```
case Direction::UP:
    --new_head_pos.second;
    new_head_pos.first = snake_body[0].first;       
    break;

// ...
```

#### Coordinates

Rather than use an `std::pair<int, int>` as the coordinate (and have all the other code know about its internals) I'd define a `Coordinate` class that knows how to do the things you have to do with coordinates (e.g., compare them):

```
class Coordinate {
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Coordinate(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    bool operator==(Coordinate const &b) const { 
        return x == b.x && y == b.y;
    }
};
```

#### Use of standard algorithms

Once you've defined `Coordinate`, your `Game::collides` becomes something like:

```
bool Game::collides(std::pair<int, int> coordinate, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> body)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < body.size(); i++)
        if (coordinate == body[i])
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

This, in turn, can be written something like:

```
bool Game::collides(Coordinate const &coordinate, std::vector<Coordinate> const &body) { 
     return std::find(body.begin(), body.end(), coordinate) != body.end();
}
```

Of course, if you take the previous advice, the external interface to this would simplified a bit further, because it would be a member of the `Snake` class:

```
class Snake { 
    std::vector<Coordinate> body;
public:
    bool collides(Coordinate const &point) { 
        return std::find(body.begin(), body.end(), point) != body.end();
    }

    // ...        
};
```